# Displaying categories across sites with Multi Site manager

Tags: categories, multi-site-manager

I have a Multi Site Manager installation with Sites A and B set up.

Site A contains a channel, "Foo" which has a number of category groups assigned to it.

On Site A, I can easily show a list of categories with:

```
{exp:channel:categories category_group="1" style="linear" show_empty="yes"}
{category_name}<br>
{/exp:channel:categories}
```

This outputs a list of category names as expected.

I need to do the same on Site B. But using the same code shows nothing.
I tried adding a site parameter, a site_id parameter, specifying the channel name, specifying the sitename:channel name. All to no avail.

How can I show the list of categories on Site B?

Comment: What version of EE?

Comment: It's version 2.9.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it in the past this way:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT cat_id, cat_name, cat_url_title FROM exp_categories WHERE group_id = 'xxx'"}
```

Comment: Did you do it that way because the regular categories tags didn't work across MSM sites?

Comment: Correct, I was having trouble getting it to work across sites, and needed it done in a hurry......

Comment: In the end I opted for custom queries as described here.

Answer (score 0):

Using the **show="category_ids"** should work, though that's the individual category ids. Not sure about category groups.

Also, maybe not specific to this, but **relaxed_categories="yes"** helps with a lot of category indicator URL problems working with MSM.

GWcode Categories may help, as well: http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories